# Ionic 3 search saving result how to clear it

Tags: angular, ionic-framework

I am facing some issue in search option when i type input its showing search result but when i clear input it save the list and then if i type other input its searching from first search list
Example
List is apple, appricot, bannana , mango , orange
when i search "ap" its showing apple and appricot which is ok
but when i clear input and tpe bananana its not showing result because its save the 2 values in list

```
<ion-header>
  <ion-navbar color="primary">
    <ion-title color="primary">Hospital</ion-title>
  </ion-navbar>

    <ion-toolbar color="primary">
    <ion-searchbar    [(ngModel)]="searchTerm"
    (ionChange)="setFilteredItems()"></ion-searchbar>
  </ion-toolbar>

</ion-header>

<ion-content padding>

    <ion-item *ngFor="let d of list" (click)="gotoDetails(d)">
        <div style="font-size: 16px;">{{d.Name}}</div>
          <ion-icon name="pin" color="primary"></ion-icon> <font style="font-size: 14px;">{{d.City}}</font>
          <ion-icon ios="ios-arrow-forward" md="md-arrow-forward" item-right color="primary" class="pin"></ion-icon>

    </ion-item>

</ion-content>
```

.ts

```
  filterItems(searchTerm) {
    return this.list.filter(list => {
      return list.Name.toLowerCase().indexOf(searchTerm.toLowerCase()) > -1;
    });
  }


  setFilteredItems() {
    this.list = this.filterItems(this.searchTerm);
  }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make a copy of the list inside `ngOnInit()` or the `constructor` as below

```
 ngOnInit(){
      this.listCopy = this.list;
    }

   filterItems(searchTerm) {
       return this.list = this.listCopy.filter(list => {
          return list.Name.toLowerCase().indexOf(searchTerm.toLowerCase()) > -1;
        });
    }

    setFilteredItems() {
       this.list = this.filterItems(this.searchTerm);
    }
```